# Is eCPMs dropping by about 50% in January a usual behavior on Google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

So I just got semi-serious about running some AdSense sites over the past 6 months and the eCPM's have hovered between 1.38 and 1.42 [yes it's that close] when I look at the eCPM for each month.  Obviously some deviation day to day but pretty damn close to a buck forty in aggregate.  So far for January I am sitting at 0.80 for an eCPM.  I know it's not a huge sample size but the daily pageviews are fairly consistent [actually a bit higher] than where they were in December.  I am trying to justify this by thinking that somehow a lot of ad buyers buy inventory for the year and have to get setup to do another big buy now that it's a new calendar year but that thought isn't close to comforting.

Is this happening to anyone else?

**EDIT:**  I run a lot of websites and the ratios of pageviews are about the same this month to last month but just to be clear the eCPM I posted is for >20 websites in a variety of niches, it doesn't accurately depict any one domain.

Comment: I don't think most businesses buy ads in huge bulk and just run campaigns a certain time of the year. Unless it's a major company with a big marketing budget. Most companies I work with decide on a sale to run a month or so in advance prepare the ad creatives and run the campaigns. Have you compared your text link ads vs graphic ads? Some spots on my sites like 300x250 I force graphic only ads which do pretty well. If your pageviews have not gone down I would run some reports in adsense and try and figure out what ads were better than others. Also see about disabling public service ads.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to justify this by thinking that somehow a lot of ad buyers buy inventory >for the year and have to get setup to do another big buy now that it's a new calendar >year but that thought isn't close to comforting.

How's your CTR and/or fill rate? If those are down that would suggest

1. Your mentioned scenario or something like it. They just had less relevant ads to show.
2. They changed how they optimize ads and the new method may be less efficient than predicted.

How are the rates now? If you sign up some of your inventory with another ad network you might be able to leverage the effects.

Answer (score -2):

50% might be a bit too high, but I'd say there are several possible reason as to why the decline is occuring at this time. But the main reason is..

(*) Most people are still in holiday mode(family, less computers) so advertisers are not spending as much as they would on a regular day or blackfriday etc..

It's only the first week of Jan so, people are finishing up on their break and some are starting school, give them some time to get back. Check your data by the 15th and tell us how it is.

Comment: Like I said the pageviews are not down, it's just the CPMs.

Comment: Can someone explain the reason behind the down vote?

Comment: Your answer made zero sense.  It's possible you just don't know what pageviews or CPMs are, but if that's the case you shouldn't just be spouting nonsense